# Initializing a view with custom initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

In order to initialize a view that has xib, I use `initWithCoder` function. But what if I need to initialize the xib with custom parameter.

I need something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
           andTitle:(NSString *)titleString
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.titleLabel = titleString;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And when do I call it? After `awakeFromNib`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't modify the `initWithCoder:` method like that because the method is defined in a protocol you don't control. Instead you need to either call the `setTitle:` method after the object has been created, possibly in `awakeFromNib`, or from the owning controller.

Comment: you would not set the custom field in awakeFromNib

Comment: @SÄN why would you not set the text of a label in awakeFromNib ?

Answer (score 9):

You don't call initWithCoder yourself, usually, so you can't pass custom parameters to it. That method would be called by the nib loading mechanism and you don't have control over it.

You certainly wouldn't call it from awakeFromNib - the object would already have been initialised by that point so you couldn't re-call it.

The simplest solution is to expose your custom parameters as properties and just set them after you've created the view.

Comment: Agreed, I sure wish I could create a custom init method to pass along parameters so it happens all in one go.

Comment: What about Swift ... if i want to pass my custom properties in initwithcoder method which i would like to declare as let .... how can i do that ?